# How to run django extra query with url request params

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to run a query on a database (in django) that orders objects by proximity or "farness". The view takes the user's longitude and latitude using `self.request.query_params.get('latitude', None)` and `self.request.query_params.get('longitude', None)` I run a select query, making calculations with the fetched variable.
After googling, I came up with the following view function using `queryset.extra`

```
class FuelStationByLocation(generics.ListAPIView):
serializer_class = FuelStationSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = FuelStation.objects.all()
    latit = self.request.query_params.get('latitude', None)
    longit = self.request.query_params.get('longitude', None)
    if latit is None:
        return queryset
    ordered_queryset = queryset.extra(select = {'farness': 'select ((latitude-%f) * (latitude-%f)) + ((longitude-%f) * (longitude-%f))'
        %(float(latit), float(latit), float(longit), float(longit)),}, order_by = ['farness',])
    return ordered_queryset
```

But after running , I get a `ProgrammingError` `syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ...latitude" FROM "fuelmate_fuelstation" ORDER BY "farness" ASC`

Any idea what the source of this error is? Or a better way to implement such a feature will be gladly appreciated.

Edited to include entire class based view. I'm using Django Rest Framework and overriding the get_queryset function.

Running the query with constants worked fine with no error. So I'm guessing it has something to do with my syntax in including the request parameters.

Thanks

Comment: is this all the code? I feel there's more

Comment: Hi, just added an edit to show the class containing the function. I already tried the query with constants in the calculation and it didn't give any error

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem, but you could always use `print ordered_queryset.query` to examine what's the raw query string produced by your `extra` statement, maybe copying the raw result and run it in your dbshell.

Comment: @ShangWang Good idea will try that and post the result

Comment: Why don't you use GeoDjango for spacial queries? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/

Comment: @AlexeyKuleshevich I considered it but I figured it'll be overkill since it was just one proximity query I planned on running and I seem so close to figuring it out without resorting to GeoDjango

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the helpful comments guys. In the end @AlexeyKuleshevich 's comment helped the most. Testing the query in the shell with various inputs showed that all worked fine with positive inputs for "longit" and "latit"; the error only showed itself when I tested with negative longitudes or latitudes. So I just ended up enclosing all my %fs in brackets to prevent any negative signs meeting head on, for example, 'latitude -- 60.1001' will become 'latitude - (-60.1001)' instead. 
I ended up with the following query:

```
ordered_queryset = queryset.extra(select = {'farness': 'select ((latitude-(%f)) * (latitude-(%f))) + ((longitude-(%f)) * (longitude-(%f)))'
        %(float(latit), float(latit), float(longit), float(longit)),}, order_by = ['farness',])
```

And it worked like a charm!
Hope it helps someone else out there. Thanks again ;)